# Getting total number of entries which meet condition php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, count

I have a database which contains fisheries in different regions. I am using the command below:

```
    $sql ="SELECT region FROM table WHERE region='Fife'";
    $res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
        $total = array ($sql);
        echo count($total);
```

This gives me (111111111111111) as an output. However i am looking for it to return (15) instead. There are currently only 15 enteries which match 'Fife'

Can anyone suggest how i can improve my code to get the desired results??

Comment: You get how many 1's? You're doing `$total = array($sql)`, so $total is always an array with just 1 element: $sql

Comment: get 15 1's which is the correct amount. just want it to say 15 instead of all the 1's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$sql ="SELECT region FROM table WHERE region='Fife'";
    $res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$total = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
$total[] = array ($sql);
}
echo count($total);
```

If you want to keep the records

Comment: You're doing it wrong. It should be `$total[] = $row['region'];`

Comment: @PerroAzul Thanks for the added comment that seemed to work correctly.

Answer (score 4):

Use MySQL's [`count()`](http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlcount.php) :

```
$sql ="SELECT count(*) AS total FROM table WHERE region='Fife'";
$res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
echo $row['total'];
```

Comment: This just gives me () no value?

Comment: It should be `$row['total']` in the last line.

Comment: Correct. Mis-typed on my part.

Comment: I dont know if i have mis understood but have corrected last line to $row['total'] but still get ()

Comment: This works fine and it's the best way to do it if you don't need to keep the records. Maybe you should check if you typed the sql correctly, especially the `count(*) AS total` part.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually do the count in SQL, which is a lot faster.

```
$sql ="SELECT COUNT (*) FROM table WHERE region='Fife'";
$c = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
print $c;
```